# Bootstrap(4) - multiple tables in columns spill outside parent element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im using Bootstrap (4 beta) and trying to display two tables in two side by side columns. However they aren't being contained in the parent element for some reason and can't figure out how to change the layout correctly. The pic at the bottom shows how it's currently being rendered.
(browser target is ie10 and above)

```
<div class="quote">
    <h6>data</h6>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div><img src="" alt="" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__"></div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>data</p>
        <p>data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>Key features:</p>
        <p>Fixed<br>data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col savings">

        <h6 class="text">data</h6>

        <h4>data</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-cta-secondary btn-sm" data-id="83145667" id="button">More Info</button>

          <a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="/users/profile/83145667">Proceed</a>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row til" id="til83145667" style="">
      <table class="table col-lg-4">

        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="col-lg-4 table">

        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1: Your rows and cols need to be in a `container` e.g.

```
<div class="quote container">
    <h6>data</h6>
        <div class="row">
            [...]
```

2: Don't add the `col` classes directly to the `<table> element` - put the table in a div that has that class, e.g.

```
<div class="row til" id="til83145667" style="">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <table class="table">
            [...]
```

**Working Snippet** (Note, I've added a border to the tables to make them clear):

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #009999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="quote container">
  <h6>data</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div><img src="" alt="" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__"></div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>data</p>
      <p>data</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>Key features:</p>
      <p>Fixed<br>data</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col savings">

      <h6 class="text">data</h6>

      <h4>data</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-cta-secondary btn-sm" data-id="83145667" id="button">More Info</button>

      <a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="/users/profile/83145667">Proceed</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row til" id="til83145667" style="">
    <div class=" col-lg-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <table class=" table">

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks having the col classes assigned directly to the tables was the main issues.

Comment: @Yunti Glad to help! Yes the col classes were breaking the "side-by-side" tables, but the container class is also needed for correct margins and padding - without it, the first row of your example actually had a negative left margin and was hidden off the left of the page.

Comment: Thanks that's ok I actually had a container already higher up in the page, and just pulled out the relevant bit, but I should have included it for clarity (and the benefit of others who look at this question).   Thanks again.